# Is it possible to use trace 32 functionality from command line not gui?

Tags: cmd, automation, trace32, lauterbach

its a quick question just wondering if i can use Trace 32 functionality like flashing,break points and watch variables through command line and script without the GUI for automation process?
and if its possible would there be a good link to read about how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options to use TRACE32 functionality without using the GUI*:

- You can start TRACE32 with a startup script by adding the command line option `-s <script>`. More information is available in [debugger_user.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/debugger_user.pdf) chapter "Command Line Arguments for Starting TRACE32".
- You can use the TRACE32 Remote API. You can use the TRACE32 Remote API in shell scripts (by using the precompiled binaries) or in C programs or Python scripts. More information is available in [api_remote_c.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/api_remote_c.pdf) and [app_python.pdf](https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/app_python.pdf).

*The PowerView process is still required. You can start PowerView without a GUI by setting `SCREEN=OFF` in the config file.

```
;Other settings separated by an empty line

;Screen Settings
SCREEN=OFF

;Other settings separated by an empty line
```

All PDFs are also inside your TRACE32 installation.

Comment: You still need the PowerView GUI app to be running on a remote machine in order to use the API. You cannot control the debugger directly.

Comment: You are right, one cannot control the hardware directly, you'll always need the PowerView process, but you don't need the GUI. You can start PowerView without a GUI.

Comment: You're right, there is an option that I have been missing: SCREEN=OFF in config.t32 that allows running scripts without the GUI. Actually I've just noticed you edited your post to include it. Thumbs up!